# Pass Nested Dictionary as Function Arguments

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that I'm trying to traverse through the arguments of a function. My guess is that I would have to define another function to traverse the dictionary through the `get_info` function. How can I accomplish this? I appreciate any help.

```
system_dict = {"system01": {"item": "329517", "model": "P6000"},
               "system02": {"item": "329270", "model": "P7000"},
               "system03": {"item": "350510", "model": "P7000"},
               "system04": {"item": "351487", "model": "P6000"},
               "system05": {"item": "351565", "model": "P7000"},
               }

def get_info(SYSTEM, ITEM, MODEL):
    print(SYSTEM, ITEM, MODEL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use the same names for the arguments and dictionary keys, you can do it like this:

```
sd = {
    "sys1": {"item": 11, "model": 12},
    "sys2": {"item": 22, "model": 22},
}

def get_info(system, item, model):
    print(system, item, model)

for system, item_model in sd.items():
    get_info(system, **item_model)
```

This outputs:

```
('sys1', 11, 12)
('sys2', 22, 22)
```

However, that may not be a good idea, in case the keys change, or some entries have a different structure. So perhaps it's better to just explicitly extract the values you need. For example

```
for system, value in sd.items():
    item = value["item"]
    model = value["model"]
    get_info(system, item, model)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting both options. I used the second option to explicitly extract the values.